# TypeORM updating entity/table

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, typeorm

This is my User entity:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
userId: number;

@Column({type:"varchar", length:"300"})
userName: string;

@OneToOne(type => UserProfile, {cascadeAll:true})
@JoinColumn()
userProfile: UserProfile;

@OneToOne(type => UserCredential, {cascadeAll:true, eager:true})
@JoinColumn()
userCredential: UserCredential;

@OneToOne(type => BusinessUnit, {cascadeAll:true})
@JoinColumn()
businessUnit: BusinessUnit;

@ManyToMany(type => ProductCategory)
@JoinTable()
productCategory: ProductCategory[];
```

and this is my new data which i want to update:

```
User {
  userName: 'qweret@gmail.com',
  userProfile: 
   UserProfile {
     firstName: 'dcds',
     lastName: 'Faiz',
     mobile: '42423423',
     addressLine1: 'Delhi',
     addressLine2: 'Delhi',
     city: '-',
     country: '-',
     zipCode: '234243',
     homeTelephone: '-',
     dayOfBirth: 0,
     monthOfBirth: 0,
     yearOfBirth: 0 },
  userCredential: UserCredential { credential: 'abcd@123' } }
```

i'm searching user by its userId.

```
return await getManager()
               .createQueryBuilder(User, "user")
               .where("user.userId = :id", {id})
               .getOne();
```

the above query gives me result:

```
User {
  createdDate: 2018-03-29T06:45:16.322Z,
  updatedDate: 2018-04-01T06:28:24.171Z,
  userId: 1,
  userName: 'qweret@gmail.com' }
```

i want to update my user table and its related tables

```
manager.save(user)
```

will insert a new row in the table instead of updating the existing the row. Is there a way to update the whole user table and its related table without updating every column manually?
i don't want to perform this task like this:

```
let user = await userRepositiory.findOneById(1);
user.userName = "Me, my friends and polar bears";
await userRepository.save(user);

let userProfile = await userProfileRepository.findOneById(1);
 userProfile.firstName = "";
 userProfile.lastName = "";
    ....// etc
 await userRepository.save(userProfile);

 // and so on update other tables.
```

Comment: Hi, did u find any work around for your problem?

Comment: the update method requires a find criteria (it can be the id) so it can now which row to update

Answer (score 20):

Try this method:

```
await this. userRepository.update(
                user.id ,
                user
              );

const updatedUser = await this.repository.findOne(user.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `manager.save(Object.assign(oldUser, newUser))` which will save all the fields that exist in the queried user, but with all the updates you defined in the data you want to update

Answer (score 0):

we can update using the repository save method. It accepts a model object.

Step1: Fetch model using `find` methods 
Step 2: Make changes to model 
Step 3: Finally call the save method of the repository.

```
const photoToUpdate = await photoRepository.findOne(photoId)
photoToUpdate.name = "updated name"
await photoRepository.save(photoToUpdate)
```

Comment: This is not transactional....