# How to update a ManyToMany relation with TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a candidate entity with many "ManyToMany" relations, I need to create an update function for this entity.
Here is my candidate entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class Candidate {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
    
    ...

    @ManyToMany(() => Language, { nullable: true })
    @JoinTable()
        languages: Language[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Tool, { nullable: true })
    @JoinTable()
        tools: Tool[];

    @ManyToMany(() => ActivityArea, { nullable: true })
    @JoinTable()
        activity_areas: ActivityArea[];

    ...

    @Column({ nullable: true })
        desired_starting_date: string;

    ...
}
```

Language entity (the others are similar):

```js
@Entity()
export class Language {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;

    @Column({unique: true})
        name: string;
}
```

I tried to use the update function of typeORM :

```js
async update(id: number, updateCandidateDto: UpdateCandidateDto) {
    try {
        const candidate = this.generateaCandidate(updateCandidateDto); // this is the new value of candidate

        return await this.candidateRepository.update({
            id
        }, {
            languages: candidate.languages,
            tools: candidate.tools,
            activity_areas: candidate.activity_areas,
            desired_starting_date: candidate.desired_starting_date
        });
    } catch (error) {
        throw new HttpException(error.detail, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

But I got the following error : `Error: Cannot query across many-to-many for property tools`

I check the following post before posting this one:
[Update a many-to-many relationship with TypeORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137386/update-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-typeorm)
[Typeorm (Nestjs) update ManyToMany relation when using querybuilder violates not-null constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73507196/typeorm-nestjs-update-manytomany-relation-when-using-querybuilder-violates-not)
[TypeORM updating entity/table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596061/typeorm-updating-entity-table)

Can you help me to build an update function that allows me to update several ManyToMany parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a way to did it :

```js
async update(id: number, updateCandidateDto: UpdateCandidateDto) {
    try {
        const new_candidate = await this.generateCandidate(updateCandidateDto);

        for (const prop in new_candidate) {
            if (typeof new_candidate[prop] == 'object') {
                const actualRelationships = await this.candidateRepository
                    .createQueryBuilder()
                    .relation(Candidate, prop)
                    .of(id)
                    .loadMany();
                
                await this.candidateRepository
                    .createQueryBuilder()
                    .relation(Candidate, prop)
                    .of(id)
                    .addAndRemove(new_candidate[prop], actualRelationships);
            } else {
                const json = JSON.parse(`{ "${prop}" : "${new_candidate[prop]}" }`);
                    
                this.candidateRepository
                   .createQueryBuilder()
                   .update(Candidate)
                   .set(json)
                   .where('id = :id', {id: id})
.execute();
            }
        }

        return await this.findOne(id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new HttpException('Update failed', HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I test each property of the candidate I want to modify, if the property is of type 'object' it means that it is a foreign key. In this case, I retrieve all its relations from the database and replace them with the new relations.

This solution works, I will use it until a better solution is proposed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).